# Top 5 List SSMS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Query I'm having trouble with:

```
select 
    title_name, top 5 sales as tot_copies_sold,  
    a.au_lname + ', ' + a.au_fname as author_name,
    sales * price as revenue
from 
    titles t
join 
    title_authors ta on ta.title_id = t.title_id
join 
    authors a on a.au_id = ta.au_id
where 
    ta.au_order = 1
order by 
    sales desc
```

Is there any way to move the

```
top 5 sales as tot_copies_sold
```

after

```
title_name
```

in the select clause? I'm using SSMS and getting an error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 108
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'top'.

Must the 'top' keyword always follow select? Or can I use a subquery somehow?

NOTE: this is for a class. Column order doesn't really matter - The above solution works - its just for my own education to see if it is possible to move 'top'. Here is the question: *8.    Create a view to represent the best sellers list for titles.  Output only the top 5 best sellers by number of copies sold.  Include the title_name, the first author, total copies sold, and the total revenue generated.*

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing there isnt a top in your query the output would be ordered by the sales amount and the corresponding title_name.

```
select title_name, sales as tot_copies_sold,  
       a.au_lname + ', ' + a.au_fname as author_name,
       sales * price as revenue
  from titles t
  join title_authors ta
    on ta.title_id = t.title_id
  join authors a
    on a.au_id = ta.au_id
 where ta.au_order = 1
 order by sales desc
```

By applying a top(5) you are directing the query to get you the first 5 records from the ordered list. Think of top(n) as

```
select * from (
    select title_name, sales as tot_copies_sold,  
           a.au_lname + ', ' + a.au_fname as author_name,
           sales * price as revenue,
           row_number() over(order by sales) as rnk 
      from titles t
      join title_authors ta
        on ta.title_id = t.title_id
      join authors a
        on a.au_id = ta.au_id
     where ta.au_order = 1
     order by sales desc
)x where x.rnk<=5
```

ie from your original query ordered by sales amount, rank them and get the ranks 1 upto 5.

So, no the top cannot be used on the "top sales", the top is applied to the result set of your query and so it should be the first keyword in your select.